# Storyboard does not changes the view after uialertview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, uialertview

I have troubles when I perform a UIAlertView, (the alert view works fine) but... i cannot perform the segue to another window... the type of transition is modal... any help?

```
if([txtPeticion hasText] )
{
   alertaVeladora = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Santuario Virtual" 
                          message:@"Gracias por compartir tu veladora!" 
                          delegate:self 
                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertaVeladora show];  
    [self postMessage:txtPeticion.text shareTw:shareTwitter shareFb:shareFacebook withEmail:email];
    txtPeticion.text = @"";
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlert:) withObject:alertaVeladora afterDelay:1.0f];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to perform the segue when the user presses the dismiss button on the AlertView? To perform an action when the button has been pressed, use the following code:

```
if([txtPeticion hasText] )
{
   alertaVeladora = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Santuario Virtual" 
                      message:@"Gracias por compartir tu veladora!" 
                      delegate:self 
                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alertaVeladora show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex  
{
    if(alertView.tag == 1)
    {
        // Perform Segue
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"MySegue" sender: self];

    }
}
```